# Opencv - trouble creating matrix from other matrix (malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion )

Tags: opencv, malloc, mat

I'm creating a new `Mat` by jumping pixels of the original image, but I get this error:

```
PRM algorithm: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

My code is:

```
int width = round(img.cols / M);
int height = round(img.rows / M);

cv::Mat res(height, width, CV_8U);

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        res.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i * M, j * M)[0];
        res.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i * M, j * M)[1];
        res.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i * M, j * M)[2];
    }
}

return res;
```

I also tried using `uchar* ptr = img.ptr<uchar>(i)` and `ptr[j]` so it's possible to access the data directly, but I receive the same error.

I was searching, and tried some "solution" such as [sYSMALLOc: Assertion Failed error in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240496/sysmalloc-assertion-failed-error-in-opencv), but the trouble keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this error occurs when you try to access memory at an invalid location. Your code has two issues that contribute to the problem.

**First**, you access elements of `res` with `cv::Vec3b`, which implies a three-channel image, but you initialize it as single channel. Change the initialization to:

```
cv::Mat res(height, width, CV_8UC3);    // Needs to be three channels!
```

**Second**, `.at<>(i, j)` accesses elements by their row index `i` and column index `j`. However, your `i` and `j` indices refer to column and row, respectively. Your iteration limits should be swapped:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
// ...
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks, yesterday I found the first error, but the second one... I feel a little bit "stupid" hahah. Thanks again!